# Static HashMap giving incorrect result

Tags: java, hashmap

I have implemented program to find unique permutations of elements in input list. I have used backtracking and I am using map to prevent repetitive recursion.

Initially, first entry in map is: `Key="", Value=[[]]`.
However, when I add more entries, the value in first entry gets modified. I am not able to understand the reason.

Below is the code-

```
public static void main(String[] ar){
        
    List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
        
    find(l);
}
    
static Map<String,List<List<Integer>>> map=new HashMap<>();
    
public static List<List<Integer>> find(List<Integer> numbers){
    String s="";
    for(Integer i:numbers){
        s+=Character.forDigit(i,10); 
    }

    if(map.containsKey(s)){
        System.out.println(map.get(s));
        return map.get(s);
    }
    else if(numbers.isEmpty()){
        List<List<Integer>> list=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(l);
        //System.out.println(list);
        updateMap("", list);
        
        return list;
    }
        
    List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>(numbers);
    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
        
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
        if(!set.contains(numbers.get(i))){
            set.add(numbers.get(i));
        
            list.remove(i);
                
            List<List<Integer>> li=find(list);
            for(List it:li){
                it.add(0, numbers.get(i));
                System.out.println(it);
                result.add(it);
            }
            
            list.add(i, numbers.get(i));
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println("Result "+result);
    updateMap(s,result);
        
    return result;
}
    
public static void updateMap(String s,List<List<Integer>> result){
    map.put(s, result);
    System.out.println("Put in map "+map);
}
```

Following is the result after first 2 steps-

```
First entry-> =[[]]
map {=[[]]}

Second entry-> 2=[[2]]
map {=[[2]], 2=[[2]]} -> it should have been {=[[]], 2=[[2]]}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. Are you breaking your code and or explanation down in parts? -> Initial state -> find code -> output -> current output -> expected output.

Comment: Why is your `find` function putting elements in the map? If you need to put elements, create a different function. This is CLEARLY a violation of Single Responsibility Principle and most likely the reason why your code is not working as intended.

Comment: @SedJ601 I have explained different parts of the program:

First entry that is going into the map-> Key="", Value=[[]] .        Next entry that is going into the map-> Key="2", Value=[[2]] .      But after first two entries, map is containing these entries-> **{=[[2]], 2=[[2]]}** when it should have been   **{=[[]], 2=[[2]]}**

Comment: @hfontanez I have rectified that concern. Please check now.

Comment: How? Looks basically the same to me.

Comment: I ran your code. In the first input, you get a return of [2]. Break your code down into parts. `Find` should only find. You need an `Insert` method to only add elements to the `Map`. You got the `Find` method doing both. That is probably why your code is hard to follow and why you are having difficulty pinpointing your logical error.

Comment: @SedJ601 Hey, thanks for the suggestion! I figured it out.